# Use .exe file in android application

Tags: java, android, c++

There is a way to put a computer program with .exe extensions in the Android program and then run them through the program.

I have read about ndk and win, but I do not know exactly how to use them

Please describe with an example or give full reference

Comment: why on earth would you want to run a .exe on an android platform???

Comment: Executable programs written and built for a specific target can't be used on other targets without some kind of support. And I really doubt Android have support for running Windows executable files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no doubt there'll be some VM (out there) that makes it possible.

Comment: How about this https://www.techweed.net/how-to-convert-exe-to-apk-in-android/   but not sure it will work.

Comment: Since this is tagged with c++ and java, do you have access to the code in question? Because if that's the case, then surely there would be a better way to get it running on Android than compiling it for Windows and kludging a VM/Wine around it.

Comment: Thank you all of your dear friends for your advice. In reply, my dear friend, for what it is like to try to implement a computer program on Android, there is a shortage of time to write a specific program many times. I mean, this saves you time to write an Android app and saves thousands of new errors that engage you.

Comment: This is straight up an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). So let's pivot this question to get to the underlying issue. **What are you really trying to do?** If it's cross-platform development, there are  A LOT of well understood solutions. None of which involve running an EXE on an Android OS. Please be more open about what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I bought an executable file for the computer, but I do not have a source for it. But I want to create a program for Android that I can use whenever and wherever I wanted, but I did not have the time to write the full program.
I'm trying to make this app faster, on the one hand, the programmer of the computer program dead and I no longer have access to source code for him to buy from him.

Comment: Sound not like a platform independend solution - also could be missinterpreted as virus attack! So please don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run a binary application (intel x86 .exe for windows) on a different architecture and platform (android running on ARM or Arch64).

I can think of three options:

### Option 1: Emulation

The traditional approach to running binaries for different architectures is emulation, for example using [Qemu](https://www.qemu.org/).

However, that still leaves the different platform. If your exe file uses a GUI and a filesystem, for example, you suddenly also need to emulate parts of the operating system it expects, or ship a copy of some Windows variant with your application, which would have all kinds of copyright constraints.

Finally, keep in mind that Android devices have completely different input mechanism than a traditional Windows PC, so you would have to link the Android virtual keyboard (and touch events) to a keyboard and mouse for the emulated Windows PC.

This is not impossible, but will require a tremendous amount of supporting code.
If you choose to go this route, I suggest you first buy a desktop-like ARM device like a Raspberry Pi and get it working there.

### Option 2: Decompilation and porting to Android

You can find decompilers that turn the .exe file back into a set of compilable C or C++ files. This would allow you to carefully extract the functionality you need and wrap it in Android native code. This was how [OpenRCT2](https://openrct2.org/) and [Diablo](https://github.com/galaxyhaxz/devilution) were ported to other platforms like Linux and macOS, years later.

You should not expect the decompiled source code to resemble anything you would write yourself, but with enough time you can end up with something Android-native (or linux, or macOS, or even iOS).

### Option 3: Host the application elsewhere

Finally, you could opt to NOT port the application to Android at all, but rather host it on a Windows machine you can run 24/7, and make it accessible on your phone. Depending on the application, this could take the form of a web service that runs the .exe with input from the web, or a full-blown remote desktop/VNC session where you can interact with the application using your phone's input methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for the details and your help